# php AD ldap search filter specific OUS

Tags: php, ldap, ou

Here is my AD structure
[AD structure , running ldap query with php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNCGr.png)

```
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$term = $_GET["term"];

$rAD = ldap_bind($ds, $admin, $passwd);
$andThis="(&(cn=*$term*)(objectClass=User))";

$results1ADl = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $andThis);

$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $results1ADl);


for ($i = 0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {

    $fullname[$i] = $info[$i]['cn'][0];
}
```

Need to exclude all OU's under "search" except for the highlighted OU's , labeled 1 and 2.
what is the best method to do this?